# VBA pass variables between Sub and Public Function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and am trying to pass a string from a Sub to a Public Function (the Sub and Public Function are in separate modules but the same Workbook), split the string into an array in the Public Function, then pass the array back to the Sub from the Public Function.

I've searched though Stack Overflow and tried several different methods but they haven't worked. Below is the code I currently have which produces the following error:

Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range

Any help would be appreciated. Apologies for the basic question. Thank you.

Sub:

```
Sub export()
Dim testString As String
Dim testValue As Variant

'testString could have any number of values
testString = "TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4"

'Call the Public Function below
testValue = splitText(testValue)

End Sub
```

Which calls the following Public Function in another module:

```
Public Function splitText() As Variant
Dim testValue As Variant

'Trying to import testString from the Sub to split it
testValue = Split(testString, ",")

'Define result of the Public Function
splitText = testValue

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use consistent variable names and pass argument in function call

```
Public Sub export()

    Dim testString As String
    Dim testValue As Variant

    testString = "TEST1, TEST2, TEST3, TEST4"

    testValue = splitText(testString) '<== consistent naming and passed as argument 

End Sub

Public Function splitText(ByVal testString As String) As Variant '<== argument referenced in function signature
    Dim testValue As Variant

    testValue = Split(testString, ",") '<== consistent naming 

    splitText = testValue

End Function
```

Comment: thank you so much, it works! Why do you use `ByVal` for passing the `testString` into the Public Function? I assume by placing `testString` in the brackets after the Public Function name passes the variable into the Function (this line - `Public Function splitText(ByVal testString As String) As Variant`)?

Comment: That isn't what `ByRef` means. The fact that an `Object` is a reference *type* doesn't have anything to do with `ByVal` or `ByRef`. Passing something `ByRef` means that the called procedure gets a reference (basically a pointer) passed on the stack. This means that changes in the called procedure propagate back to the calling function.  It doesn't matter if it's an `Object` or an intrinsic type.  Try `Sub Foo(ByRef bar As Object): Set bar = Nothing: End Sub` and then test the value in the calling procedure...

Comment: This is explained in detail in [section 5.3.1.11 of the VBA language spec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156838.aspx).

Comment: @Comintern I didn't mean to imply that all objects are passed ByRef, oops, but thanks for the additional info. I will amend my comment.

Comment: You are not altering the value of testString so you are passing the actual value of it i.e. ByVal. If you were passing a reference it would be ByRef. See [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx) for more info

Comment: No, you are actually passing a *copy* of the string on the stack. cpearson.com is incorrect. For intrinsic types "If the parameter has no argument mapped to it, the parameter is ByVal, or the parameter is ByRef and the mapped argument’s expression is classified as a value, function, property or unbound member, a local variable is defined with procedure extent within the procedure being invoked with the same name value and declared type as the parameter, and has its value assigned as follows..."

Comment: For `ByVal` objects: "Otherwise, if the value type of this parameter’s mapped argument is a specific class or Nothing, the argument’s data value is Set-assigned to the new local variable." For `ByRef` objects: "When the procedure terminates, if it has terminated normally, the value within the local variable is Set-assigned back to the argument’s referenced variable."

Comment: ByVal is the correct usage in answer, no? It is my comment that is incorrect or do I need to amend the answer?

Comment: Absolutely. `ByVal` should be used in this case as an explicit contract that calling `splitText` will not alter the value of `testString` in the calling procedure. I was responding to deleted comment.

Comment: @user556511 I think you're confused on your initial question about `ByVal`. Change the function signature to `Public Function splitText(ByVal inputString As String) as Variant`. Now, you call it from `export` with the line `testvalue = splitText(textString)` and `textString` is "mapped" to the parameter `inputString`. I think your confusion was the fact that you used the local var name in `export` as the parameter name in `splitText`. When they're different, it's easier to see that these are different variables.